# Selenium PhantomJS throws EelementNotVisible while Firefox is completely fine during combo box selection

Tags: python, firefox, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs

So I have a website which has a combo that I need to select an item from, now the problem is it's a bit untraditional and doesn't have option's as elements but instead it has divs.

So I need my program to click combo box then wait (the best way to do this I found is via implicitly_wait(3)# 3 seconds) and then click the box element I need. Firefox is doing a great job with it but PhantomJS seem to throw:

```
Selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: 
Message: 'Error Message => \'Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated\'
```

I'm not sure what's the cause of it, but I suspect that PhantomJS fails to correctly wait via implicitly_wait for some reason and tries to select non-visible element.

Any idea how to approach this without forced thread sleep?

Comment: Does it work with `Thread.sleep`? If not, are there page errors? If bind is affected you may need a [shim](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522#issuecomment-39248521) that you would execute with `execute_script`.

Comment: Yes thread.sleep does seem to work, but it needs at least 3 seconds it seems, so if there are 3 combo boxes it's 9 seconds per run which is quite ridiculous, even running it straight via firefox with implicitly_wait of 3 seconds takes significantly less.

Comment: I'm also having troubles with implicitly_wait and PhantomJS. I wonder if it's not implemented in PhantomJS.

Answer (score 3):

Yup, your issue sounds exactly something I've just fixed in a UI test that was starting to anoy me. Quite a complex one, that passed on all browsers, except my favorite PhantomJs (which is the fastest).

It was quite anoying, when in the debugger I could clearly see that even the parent element was set to visible. Only the prime faces component I needed to click for whatever reason (not CSS or active Styles) was not visible.

After looking at Phantom JS screenshot, I realized the window was quite tiny, and indeed the UI element was not visually visible.

You see now where I am geting at?

Phantom JS is a headless browser, it does not render you the window, but it does use a window, and the window does have a size.
The exception is quite unexpected, because the engine behind is the same as the one used for chrome and safari ... things should just work.

Well, and they did in the end.
Try to tune your driver factory like this:

```
 WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();      
            driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
            return driver;
```

Good luck.